# Temperature profile at steady state

Tags: thermal-conductivity

> Consider a solid wall consisting of three layers where the layers are of equal
>   thickness but made out of different materials: $\ce{Layer 1}$ is made out
>   of copper (high thermal conductivity), $\ce{Layer 2}$ is made out of a
>   highly porous ceramic (low thermal conductivity), and $\ce{Layer 3}$ is
>   made out of concrete (medium thermal conductivity).
>
> How does
>   the steady state temperature profile inside the wall look like?

I'm not sure if this question is asked in a way to mislead me into drawing the T-profile as (2) when at steady-state it actually should look like (1).

I apologize if this question is seen as off-topic or simple, but I would appreciate it if someone would explain if I am correct in saying that the T-profile at steady state should be linear.

Thank you!

(1)[image]
[image] (2)

Comment: No, the stationary profile won't be linear. Why would it?

Comment: If you would provide your thoughts on why you think it might be one or the other it would be on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the temperature gradient is not uniform across all three layers.

To see why, start from the Fourier law for heat flow, shown in my solution to this [problem](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110815/determine-heat-flux-from-temperature-profile?rq=1).

Since at steady state the heat flux $q$ must be equal for all layers, we have that

$$q_{1}=q_{2}=q_{3}$$

And since the layers are equal in thickness,

$$ k_1\Delta{T_1}=k_2\Delta{T_2}=k_3\Delta{T_3} $$

Clearly, if the $k$ are not equal, the $\Delta{T}$ cannot be equal either, so the profile will not be that in (1).